# LED characteristics to use in heating a material sample?

Tags: led, microwave, induction

I am looking to be able to heat a sample of material, typically less than 500mg and sitting in a fused silica sample holder about 10mm diameter. Wondering about using (say) a 5W LED with narrow emission angle. The overall sample chamber of the machine is quite small, so ideally I need a small source, possibly with a light pipe. I certainly do not want the thermal mass of something like a halogen bulb. So, the questions...

Does this seem feasible?

What type of LED (in terms of wavelength) is the most efficient?

Does wavelength matter in terms of heating the sample? [Typically the archetypal "white powder"]

Now, I expect you to ask me what sort of temperature I want to get. The answer is "not sure", but probably 80 degC would be adequate. It is to drive off moisture.

The only cooling I have is a small ambient temperature airflow. Other possibilities (that I have not yet examined in detail) are low power uwaves and maybe changing the pan from silica to steel and using induction heating.

Comment: White stuff is hard to heat with visible light as it reflects a lot - what's the color in the infrared spectrum? If it is black there you might want to use a high power IR LED.

Comment: What problem does the thermal mass of a halogen bulb give you?

Comment: The rapidity of cooling is important as it limits the rate at which measurements can be taken. The more "stuff" that gets heated the worse the problem. 

As for IR characteristics of the material, that is unknown since it can be almost any chemical or material.

Comment: Could you attach a Peltier element to the sample holder? Reversing the polarity of the applied current switches between heating and cooling, so maybe that might work out, but the temperature difference seems a bit large for that, you'd probably need a multi stage one and I'm not sure they will be fast enough.

Comment: In case you're dismissing the halogen route prematurely, do consider that the light/heat source could be quite some distance from the sample, and that its contribution of (radiant) heat would stop pretty much instantly when you turned it off. There is an interesting thread here, which you may have seen: http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?107640-Far-Infrared-LED-possible

Comment: Depending on the design you could use some nichrome wire instead of a bulb... depending on the thickness used it should be able to heat the sample holder well as it can be formed(wound around) to hug the holder...

Comment: @Spoon We tried that route and it heats the whole chamber as well.

Comment: @Arsenal We cannot attach anything to it because it is in the process of being weighed

Comment: Any fan cooling slowed ?

Comment: @Spoon No - only a very slow well regulated gas stream

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of sample you want to heat up, but the most common way would be to use IR LEDs, like [these](https://www.google.com/search?q=5w+high+power+infrared+led). I'd use a small lens to focus the beam on the sample (could be tuned precisely enough using visible light from red LED). Make sure you protect your eyes when you power up the IR LED though - its emission is invisible and doesn't make your iris contract or your eyes hurt, so it has potential to burn your retina when visible light would be mostly harmless.

Comment: Maybe change the pan to black steel or Aluminium... However, for the reasons you mentioned I would rather use visible rather than IR